# Java STS: UCanAccess connection error "cannot load driver class"

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, spring-boot, ucanaccess

I am trying to make connection between MS Access and Java STS(web project). I tried with connection from class and it works:

public Connection getConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException{

```
    Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
    try {
        System.out.println("try");
        return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess:///home/example/Desktop/Somedb.mdb");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.out.println("catch");
        return null;            
    }

}
```

But when i try to define database connection in application.properties i get error.

> Cannot load driver class: net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver

This is my application.properties.

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:ucanaccess:///home/example/Desktop/Somedb.mdb
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver
```

I get the error when i try to run aplication on tomcat.

Comment: In what context are you running the code that is failing? Stand-alone Java (desktop) application? Web application (e.g., Tomcat)? ...? Please [edit] your question to provide more information.

Comment: Have you copied all five (5) of the required JAR files into the `/WEB-INF/lib` folder of your web application?